# Get objects with request and mapping progress in RestKit

Tags: ios, rest, core-data, restkit

Let's say I have an api like the follwing:

```
//http://example.com/api/comment/

response:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "some_user",
    "content": "content of the comment"
  },
  ...
  {
    "id": 9999,
    "username": "some_other_user",
    "content": "content of the comment"
  }
]
```

It is critical that I fetch all the objects in one request.

Since RestKit appears to be slow when mapping responses with many objects into core data the following takes very very long (more than a minute in the simulator).

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath("/api/comment/", parameters: nil, success: { (operation, result) -> Void in

        }) { (operation, error) -> Void in

    }
```

Since I couln't find a way to speed up the request/mapping I was hoping to be able to display a progress bar for the duration of this operation. Is it possible to get a progress block for the mapping with someting like `objectsToMap` and `mappedObjects`?

Comment: You could retrofit that progress tracking. You really have 10,000 items to process? That you tried profiling to see what takes th time, are you using the latest version and why must it be done in 1 request?

Comment: Can you give any detail on how I could retrofit the progress tracking?

Comment: Have you maybe found a way to track mapping progress?